# How can i import .so file in GingerBread 2.3.3?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I want to import .so file in Android Source code in Package Name in lib folder.How can i do that in Android Source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Native-NDK to build your JNI file .so  you can get the lib folder inside your JNI with filename.so file.you can not import .so file in eclipse.it will take automatically call your native code in your android java program.